# Install hypervisor on existing system, using virtual disks?

Tags: virtualization

I have an (up-to-date) 64-bit Ubuntu server which has been running for several years, and all the disk space is allocated for typical linux purposes, though with about 80 gig free space in the partitions.

I need to run a Windows virtual machine on this machine if possible (Wine is not good enough), but the hardware lives in a datacenter and I don't have access to the raw keyboard/monitor to reformat and install VMWare on the bare metal. Also I can't very easily remove the data to repartition, so I need to make do with how it is already configured.

Is there any hypervisor that:

- Can be installed and run as a regular process alongside everything else the Ubuntu server already does?
- Has a capability for virtual disks stored as a file in the existing linux partitions?
- provides access to the virtual machine console remotely without remote Xwindows capability? (For example, Windows remote desktop, or another self-contained remote viewer like VNC.)

Comment: The [kernel-based virtual machine](https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Main_Page) can be installed through default package management (look for `qemu-kvm`). Virtual disks are usually stored as `qcow2` files (ability for snapshots). The configuration can be done completely via shell commands through `virsh`. The console can be accessed via VNC or or [Spice](https://www.spice-space.org/). And depending on your access to the server (firewall, port forwarding) you can access the administration via [`virt-manager`](https://virt-manager.org/).